# How to transfer a Tracking Extract to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

The tracking extract generates a csv and has a lot more information than the respective data view. How do i export the tracking extract to a DE either with an activity or SSJS? Does anyone know if either is possible? E.g. the Click Data View is severely limited when compared to the Click Tracking Extract.

**Edit**: Bad behaviour of the moderator to close the question. I was explicit in what two use cases I tried. There's little to no value in explaining the steps more because both available options lacked options. So the question wasn't to about someone solving it for me but rather asking is this possible and if so at high level how. There is no other stack group that deals with SFMC.

Comment: you can unzip the zip file and import the csv file into a DE

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually easier to do then you might think. Like @EazyE stated, you would extract the file, use a file transfer to push it to the FTP then use another File Trasfer to unzip it. Once you have the csv files that were in the zip file onto the FTP server you can then import them.

**Step 1**: Create Data Extract - You already seem to know this, so will skip details
**Step 2**: Create File Transfer - This is the one to move it from Safehouse to a File Location (you will need to set the File location up prior to this step in admin - must be on SFMC SFTP)
**Step 3**: Create File Transfer - This is 'Manage File' Extract type, this will unzip the Tracking Extract file you created in Step 1. The files in this zip will then be sent to the SFTP.
**Step 4** Import Activity - You then create an import activity that targets the file contained inside of the zip file associated with what you want to import. This step requires you to create a target DE for the data to flow into.

From there you will have this data inside of the data extension that you can use for queries or lookups or whatever you need it for.

Comment: Very roundabout but this worked. Will end up having to do it with unsubscribes most likely as well as the data view is lacking as well.